# Order of binding to be fired

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

We are using Microsoft Office.JS to develop addin.

Just wondering, is there a way to specify the order of binding to fired?

I have two bindings bound to cell, one at row level and other at sheet level (larger area). The event handlers are getting fired okay when the user selects a cell, but not in the order I wanted.

**event handler adding snippet**

```
result.value.addHandlerAsync(Office.EventType.BindingSelectionChanged, SetUserSelection);
```

I don't find an option to specify order/priority.

Answer (score 0):

there is no way to specify the order when the events will get fired. You could, however, identify if the event is coming from the sheet or the cell assuming you have 2 different handlers each associated with its own set of cells.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Yeah, the problem is, I want to do a specific function, if only one event handler gets fired. when both gets fired, I want to do something else.  Since the order is not consistent, I dont know if the event got fired is the last event or not.